# Is the script Wes Craven is writing on his computer the movie itself?

Tags: plot-explanation, new-nightmare

In Wes Craven's New Nightmare, when Heather meets Wes at New Line, they talk about making a new movie to make Freddy stop.

At the end of this sequence, we can see that Wes is actually writing the script of "New nightmare". The dialog shown on the screen is literally what has just been said: (1:04:50)

[image: script on computer0]
[image]

This sequence ends with a fade to black, as written on the script.

I'm a bit confused about this part of the movie. At this point, is Wes both inside the movie, and writing the movie?

Comment: As rob said, you already answered your question.

Comment: Two tv tropes cover this. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecursiveCanon and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealWorldEpisode. And http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RewritingReality... And http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AuthorPowers. Damn where did the last 5 hours go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've pretty much answered your own question. The film is based on the idea of a fictional character crossing over into the real lives of the real actors who acted in the earlier films in the franchise. That Wes is writing the dialogue in a script that exactly matches the dialogue the characters have just said totally fits the crossover world being created in this film.

Comment: I find time traveling paradoxes easier to understand. Is the computer on which Wes is working the one on which he wrote the script from a New Nightmare (from our universe) ?

Comment: I don't think any time travelling is implied or suggested in this film. It's almost like that section in SpaceBalls where they rent a video of the finished SpaceBalls film to find out what happen later, except played straight.

Comment: No sorry, I meant I find easier to understand a paradoxical time travelling plot than a paradoxical crossover world. I know there is no time traveling in this movie.

Comment: In the movie's "reality," what he is writing is coming true as he writes it. His fiction is turning into "reality." It's a fake script that is "real" in the movie, not the one they used to film the actual **real** movie you saw.

Comment: Given that's the only bit we see it /could/ be the actual script they used to film against.

Comment: @user3585425 You need to watch Adaptation...